# Retorno JSON no formato desejado vindo do SQL

Tags: php, json, rest

Estou tentando obter o seguinte retorno no MySQL:

```
{
    matricula : '123',
        periodo : [
            {id : '012016', titulo: 'Janeiro 2016'},
            {id : '022016', titulo: 'Fevereiro 2016'},
            {id : '032016', titulo: 'Março 2016'}
        ]
    },
    matricula : '456',
        periodo : [
            {id : '012017', titulo: 'Janeiro 2017'},
            {id : '022017', titulo: 'Fevereiro 2017'},
            {id : '032017', titulo: 'Março 2017'}
        ]
    },
}
```

Estou utilizando o Rest do Slim com este Código:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        nu_matricula AS matricula,
        CONCAT(nu_mes, nu_ano) AS periodo,
        (CASE nu_mes 
         when 1 then CONCAT('Janeiro','/',nu_ano)
         when 2 then CONCAT('Fevereiro','/',nu_ano)
         when 3 then CONCAT('Março','/',nu_ano)
         when 4 then CONCAT('Abril','/',nu_ano)
         when 5 then CONCAT('Maio','/',nu_ano)
         when 6 then CONCAT('Junho','/',nu_ano)
         when 7 then CONCAT('Julho','/',nu_ano)
         when 8 then CONCAT('Agosto','/',nu_ano)
         when 9 then CONCAT('Setembro','/',nu_ano)
         when 10 then CONCAT('Outubro','/',nu_ano)
         when 11 then CONCAT('Novembro','/',nu_ano)
         when 12 then CONCAT('Dezembro','/',nu_ano)
      END) AS titulo
    FROM contra_cheque
    ORDER BY id_contra_cheque DESC
";

try {
    $db     = getDB();
    $stmt   = $db->query($sql);
    $users  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

    $db     = NULL;
    echo '{"dados": ' . json_encode($users) . '}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

E retorna este resultado:

```
{
    "contra_cheques": {
        "1731793": [{
            "periodo":"012018",
            "0":"012018",
            "titulo":"Janeiro\/2018",
            "1":"Janeiro\/2018"
        },{
            periodo":"122017",
            "0":"122017",
            "titulo":"Dezembro\/2017",
            "1":"Dezembro\/2017"
        },{
"periodo":"112017","0":"112017","titulo":"Novembro\/2017","1":"Novembro\/2017"},{"periodo":"102017","0":"102017","titulo":"Outubro\/2017","1":"Outubro\/2017"},{"periodo":"092017","0":"092017","titulo":"Setembro\/2017","1":"Setembro\/2017"},{"periodo":"082017","0":"082017","titulo":"Agosto\/2017","1":"Agosto\/2017"},{"periodo":"072017","0":"072017","titulo":"Julho\/2017","1":"Julho\/2017"},{"periodo":"062017","0":"062017","titulo":"Junho\/2017","1":"Junho\/2017"}]}}
```

Qual a forma para obter o resultado do JSON acima desejado??

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tratar a resposta **json** atual e converter pro formato desejado com **PHP**:

```
<?php
$arr_json = '{
   "contra_cheques":{
      "1731793":[
         {
            "periodo":"012018",
            "0":"012018",
            "titulo":"Janeiro\/2018",
            "1":"Janeiro\/2018"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"122017",
            "0":"122017",
            "titulo":"Dezembro\/2017",
            "1":"Dezembro\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"112017",
            "0":"112017",
            "titulo":"Novembro\/2017",
            "1":"Novembro\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"102017",
            "0":"102017",
            "titulo":"Outubro\/2017",
            "1":"Outubro\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"092017",
            "0":"092017",
            "titulo":"Setembro\/2017",
            "1":"Setembro\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"082017",
            "0":"082017",
            "titulo":"Agosto\/2017",
            "1":"Agosto\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"072017",
            "0":"072017",
            "titulo":"Julho\/2017",
            "1":"Julho\/2017"
         },
         {
            "periodo":"062017",
            "0":"062017",
            "titulo":"Junho\/2017",
            "1":"Junho\/2017"
         }
      ]
   }
}';

$arr = json_decode($arr_json,true);
$rs = [];
foreach($arr as $cc){
    $pps = [];
    $srs = [];
    foreach($cc as $pp){

        foreach($pp as $pps){

        $srs[] = [
            'id' => $pps['periodo'],
            'titulo' => $pps['titulo'],
            ];
        }
    }

    $rs[key($cc)]= [
        'periodo'=>$srs
        ];
}
var_dump($rs);
```

Exemplo funcional:
https://ideone.com/o7KcLV